# What is this icon on a 2018 Ford truck's radio screen?

Tags: ford, dashboard

It appears on the upper right of the radio screen.

Good user interface design would mean that this is a super important icon due to its prominent location, but I can't find any mention of it in the manual or through Google image search.  The red slash makes me think something important is turned off.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be [Ford's 911 Assist](https://owner.ford.com/support/how-tos/sync/sync/settings/how-to-use-911-assist-with-sync.html).  Perhaps being crossed out means the feature is non-functional.